# Calculating Percentage of True or False of multiple columns grouped by a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df such as:

```
 Service |  DoorDash | Grubhub / Seamless | UberEats| Caviar | Postmates | JustEat | Deliveroo | Foodora | Grab | Talabat | Tock      
 Open         True          True                True     False    True        False     False      False     False  False     False
 Closed       True          False               True     True     False       False     False      False     False  False     True
 Open         True          False               False    False    False       False     False      False     False  False     False
 Open         False         False               False    False    False       False     False      False     False  False     False
 Closed       False         False               False    True     False       False     False      False     False  False     True
 Open         False         False               False    False    False       False     False      False     False  False     False
 Closed       False         False               False    False    False       False     False      False     False  False     True  
 Closed       True          True                True     False    True        False     False      False     False  False     False
 Open         False         True                True     False    False       False     False      False     False  False     False
```

I want to run a `.value_counts(normalize=True)` on the all the columns not named Service but grouped by the service column, so my output will be the % that DoorDash and the rest of the columns are True and False but grouped or filtered for Open or Closed in the Service Column.

Expected Output:

```
    DoorDash Grubhub / Seamless ........
Open   .60        .50
Closed .40        .50
```

But for all of the columns with a True or False value not just DoorDash, but I cant seem to find a way where I can do that calculation and my output will be for all the columns ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `df.groupby('Service').mean()` if need percentage of `True`s values.

Comment: Hi, this will give me the % for each of the columns?

Comment: It give you percentage of `True`s values per `Service` and each column

Comment: Got it, I looked at the Aggregation in pandas link posted, but I dont see a clear example there, I wanted to see the percentage of true and false for all the columns like in my expected output

Comment: Not underatand your expected output, is correct? Not should be `Closed=0.5`, `Open=0.4` for `DoorDash` ?

Comment: Yes I wanted the percentage of True and False for each column ( DoordDash, Grubhub / Seamless, etc.) for both closed or Open

Comment: So need something else like `Expected Output:` in question? Sorry, I am confused now.

Comment: I wanted the expected output but for alll the columns not just DoorDash, I only showed DoorDash as an example instead of showing all

Comment: Do you want something like: `df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)`?

Comment: Just to clarify, my expected output shows only two columns being calculated, but I want all the columns with a True or False Value in my df showing up in my expected output

Comment: @ScottBoston I want all the columns in that df with a true or false value and the % they are True and false in both Open or Closed Rows

Comment: `df.set_index('Service').apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('Service').mean()`

Comment: `df.groupby('Service').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True))`

Comment: Hi thanks for the help!, are you saying to try these different solutions? Just a bit hard keep track with the comments I wish this question was not closed

Comment: Sure, reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df = (df.melt('Service')
        .groupby(['Service', 'variable'])['value']
        .value_counts(normalize=True)
        .unstack(1, fill_value=0))
print (df)
variable       Caviar  Deliveroo  DoorDash  Foodora  Grab  Grubhub / Seamless  \
Service value                                                                   
Closed  False     0.5        1.0       0.5      1.0   1.0                0.75   
        True      0.5        0.0       0.5      0.0   0.0                0.25   
Open    False     1.0        1.0       0.6      1.0   1.0                0.60   
        True      0.0        0.0       0.4      0.0   0.0                0.40   

variable       JustEat  Postmates  Talabat  Tock  UberEats  
Service value                                               
Closed  False      1.0       0.75      1.0  0.25       0.5  
        True       0.0       0.25      0.0  0.75       0.5  
Open    False      1.0       0.80      1.0  1.00       0.6  
        True       0.0       0.20      0.0  0.00       0.4
```